# Python Change file name based on the extesion

Tags: python

I have a dir where spark save my dataframe in csv , but it also save + 3 files extension crc.
I need upload the csv to my blob, and to do so, i need the name of the file, but spark always saves with a random name (always starting with "part") part0015154102102.csv .

I´m trying to rename the csv file to rawfile.csv , based on the previous name , that always start with part, doing a while, and removing the other file, but is not working. Is there a way to rename based on the extension?

```
path = """c:\\Users\\Cliente\\Desktop\\Notebooks\\"""

novo_nome = 'rawfile.csv'
cont = 1
while (cont < 4):
    for nome in os.listdir(dir):  
        if file[:4] == 'part':
            os.rename(path+"\\"+nome, path+"\\"+novo_nome)
        else:
            os.remove(file)                 
            cont = cont + 1
```

Comment: What is not working?  What are your expected and actual results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nome.startswith('part') and nome.endswith('.csv')` to find your file.
The code below should do what you want if I understood it correctly.

Also, you do not need the while loop, as the for will already go through all the files in the directory.

```py
import os
path = "C:\\Users\\Cliente\\Desktop\\Notebooks\\"

novo_nome = 'rawfile.csv'
cont = 1

for nome in os.listdir(path):
    # if name is what we want, change it to novo_nome
    if nome.startswith('part') and nome.endswith('.csv'):
        os.rename(path + nome, path + novo_nome)
    
    # else remove all the other files
    else:
        os.remove(path + nome)
```

#### Note: be careful with this code as it will delete everything other than a file that starts with "part" and ends with ".csv".

You can add more checks to prevent it from deleting itself (in case you put the script in the same folder) and to prevent it from deleting `rawfile.csv` if you run it again:

```py
import os
path = "C:\\Users\\Cliente\\Desktop\\Notebooks\\"

novo_nome = 'rawfile.csv'
cont = 1

for nome in os.listdir(path):
    # if name is what we want, change it to novo_nome
    if nome.startswith('part') and nome.endswith('.csv'):
        os.rename(path + nome, path + novo_nome)

    # else remove all the other files
    # except if they are a .py or a .csv
    elif not nome.endswith('.csv') and not nome.endswith('.py'):
        os.remove(path + nome)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you want to use a `.splitext()` then test for the extension.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

```
filename, extension = os.path.splitext( nome )
if extension = '.csv':
    number = filename[4:]
    print( number )
    do stuff...
```